# Parse error on systemd timer unit. Is the documentation wrong?

Tags: systemd, man, systemd-timer

Today I tried to add a systemd timer to run a service at **`0100hrs`** on the **1st Saturday of every month**. According to [man 7 systemd.timer](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/systemd.time.7.html) you can use a pair of full stop characters to specify a range of values, quote:

```
Two values separated by ".."  may be used to indicate a range of values
```

I tried and failed to get the following `OnCalendar` entry working:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sat *-*-1..7 01:00:00
```

I looked around the net for other manpages/guides and all seemed to corroborate what was said in the man 7 page. Eventually I gave up and settled for the this, which is less elegant:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sat *-*-1,2,3,4,5,6,7 01:00:00
```

This was on Ubuntu 16.04 server. Has anyone had success with the first way of entering ranges?

EDIT: My systemd version is:

- libpam-systemd/xenial-updates,now 229-4ubuntu17 amd64 [installed]
- libsystemd0/xenial-updates,now 229-4ubuntu17 amd64 [installed]
- python3-systemd/xenial,now 231-2build1 amd64 [installed]
- systemd/xenial-updates,now 229-4ubuntu17 amd64 [installed]
- systemd-sysv/xenial-updates,now 229-4ubuntu17 amd64 [installed]

Comment: Should work ok, what's your `systemd` version ?